# Are app settings backed-up (SQLite)

Tags: itunes, icloud, data-synchronization

I'm developing an app for an iphone. This applicaiton stores almost all its data in a sqlite database. As you known, support for sqlite is not built-in to the swift/objective-c framework (unlike android). Will this data be backed-up. I've read that icloud backs up app settings but would this include the sqlite database too? If it doesn't, is it backed-up using itunes?

Answer (score 1):

If the user chooses to include your app in their iCloud backup, then all the files which the app makes available for backup are backed up, such as files in the app container's Documents folder. Store your database here for it to be backed up.